# Jetpack compose,Composable placement problem

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have two Text composable and I want to place them horizontally,
,I want to make sure that the 2nd child gets its required width(wrap content),then place the 1st child such that:
if 1st child width+2nd child width>parent width , then
first place the 2nd child then give the remaining width to the 1st child.

If 1st child with+2nd child width<parent width;that means there is extra width available after placing them.in that case place the 2nd child at the end of the 1st child,by skipping the extra space.

Example as:
In Larger screen:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 2ndTextComposable
In Smaller screen:
AAAAAAAAA... 2ndTextComposable

How can I achieve that?

I tried using a custom layout but once  the children are measured I can not change the width of the child.

Comment: give Modifier.weight(1f) to the second child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a `weight` on your first text, and ensure you set the `fill` argument to `false`

```
@Preview(widthDp = 420, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TwoText() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis semper mauris mi, vel egestas tortor auctor quis. Proin lectus felis, elementum vel volutpat et, faucibus ut urna. ",
                maxLines = 1,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)
            )
            Text(
                text = "Second Text",
                color = Color.Red,
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Short first text",
                maxLines = 1,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)
            )
            Text(
                text = "Second Text",
                color = Color.Red,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]